How to copy images in a cell from Google Sheets using Apps Script?
I'm facing a problem that I don't know how I can interact with images inserted directly into a cell in Google Sheets. Conventionally, I paste a screenshot from the clipboard into a cell.
function main(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("mysheet");
 const data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();

  const folder_id = "FOLDER_ID";
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder_id);

  const doc = DocumentApp.create("KPI report");
  const id = doc.getId();

  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  file.moveTo(folder);

  const body = doc.getBody();
  body.appendTable(data);
}

My task is to copy the entire table into a Google document. I'm using this code, it works but it ignores cells that have images in them.
The .getValue() method on a cell containing an image returns: CellImage.
How can I interact with these images and copy them into my Google Doc?
.getImages() returns an empty array
.getValue() returns a string "CellImage"
.getFormula() returns nothing
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A7108653+CellImage
I tried to look for solutions here, but they don't work for me. I paste a picture into a cell directly from the clipboard, this picture does not have any url or formulas. And I want to understand how I can interact with this so that I can then copy it into a Google document.

Hi there! Just a thought, if you need to copy the entire table, maybe it'd be easier to save the spreadsheet as PDF and import it in your docs using DriveApp?

This would be a good solution, but unfortunately in this case the table disappears, only the text remains

There is no simple way to get a image that was added to a Google Sheets spreadsheet by using copy-paste to add it to another type of document or save as file in Google Drive.
Using Google Apps Script it's possible to get these images by using SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getImages() See *. This method will return an array of Class OverGridImage. Unfortunately this class hasn't methods to retrieve a blob. You might try to use SpreadsheetApp.OverGridImage.getUrl() but it's very likely that this method will return null in the case of images added by using copy-paste.
However, it might be possible to get the image by exporting the sheet to HTML and then convert this HTML file, i.e., to Google Documents format. A bit earlier I found a blog article written by Tanaike Converting Google Spreadsheet to HTML Table using Google Apps Script explaining steps to follow and including the scripts to use.
If you found the process and script explained by Tainake too complex or too hard, instead of copying the images into a spreasheet consider to copy them to a Google Slides presentation or to a Google Docs document. It might be easier to handle this images from these apps.
Images in Google Sheets
A image in Google Sheet might be added using several methods. Depending of the method used, the there are some tasks that could be done with these images using Google Apps Script.
The methods available to handle images belongs to Class CellImage and Class OverGridImage.
If you are unsure you might have to inspect your SpreasheetApp.Sheet and and the relevant Spreadsheet.Range to check if they hold the images.
It worth noting that Class CellImage has the getContentUrl() which is not available for Class OverGridImage and that, using the Google Sheets web app is possible to convert a OverGridImage into a CellImage by clicking the image options (top right corner) then Put image in selected cell.

Unfortunately the getContentUrl() method throws and error
function myFunction() {
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell();
  const value = range.getValue();
  Logger.log(range.getSheet().getName())
  Logger.log(range.getA1Notation())
  Logger.log(value);
  Logger.log(value.getContentUrl())
}

Logs (timestamp column not included)









Notice
Execution started


Info
Sheet1


Info
A1


Info
CellImage


Error
Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getContentUrl on object SpreadsheetApp.CellImage.  myFunction    @ Untitled.gs:7



Related

How to access new 'in-cell-image' from google apps script?

